# Java sampled - Play Raw PCM Wav Data

Tags: java, javax.sound.sampled

I'm working with sounds at the moment.

I obtain my byte[]'s by reading a wav file and skipping the first 44 bytes (According to WAV Specification, the data begins at byte 44).
I use 22500Hz and export it via Audacity to 16 bit PCM.

My Method looks like this

```
    private static final AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_UNSIGNED,22500f,16,1,2,2,false);

  public static void play(Sound s) throws LineUnavailableException, IOException
  {
    int selectedSample = (int) (Math.random() * ( s.samples.length ));
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    AudioInputStream ais;
    ais = new AudioInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(s.samples[selectedSample]),format,s.samples[selectedSample].length);
    clip.open (ais);
    clip.start ();
  }
```

My SoundClass looks like this

```
public class Sound
{
  public byte[][] samples;
  float pitchLow;
  float pitchHigh;
  float volumeLow;
  float volumeHigh;
  byte chance;
}
```

What am I doing wrong, I don't get an LineUnavailableException and I don't hear a thing.